# Frontend login doesn't work after website move

Tags: joomla-1.5

I have to move and update a very old Joomla-1.5 website. Since I moved it, the frontend login doesn't work anymore but the backend login does. When I try to log in, the page is just reloading. It doesn't matter if I use wrong or right login data.

In the database, I get entries in the session table but they do not contain any information about the user. So it doesn't seem to be a session issue.

New site: http://cig-online.de/intranet/joomla/index.php

Old site: http://christen-im-gesundheitswesen.de/

Does anyone have any idea where I can look next?

Thanks!

Comment: The new page is loading for me. Please add your solution and mark this question as answered.

Comment: @TerryCarter Yes, the page is loading but I can't log in. _When I try to log in, the page is just reloading_

Comment: please check if there is any overrider created for this module. It shows a number after hitting the login button and then reloads back

Comment: @Liz. thank you! It looks like that number was the problem. Deleting the function solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is that you haven't modified the tmp path and the log path in the `configuration.php` file to reflect the new environment.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it looks like this one is solved but in case others find this question, some things to check when a moved website is not working as expected:

- the .htaccess file (in particular, check the `RewriteBase /`, `Options +FollowSymLinks` lines or any non-standard lines - compare with htaccess.txt for the default settings)
- the configuration.php file, check tmp and logs paths are correct, try setting `$live_site = '';` if it's not already
- check for any `php.ini` files in the root folder and also in the /administrator folder - `php.ini` files are often not needed any more as you can configure PHP settings via cPanel or similar
- try disabling URL Rewriting in Global Configuration